# Am I allowed to offer payments with a 3rd party payment gateway, for my iPhone app?

Tags: ios, iphone, payment-gateway

So I have a RESTful Api service which has free and pay'ed stuff. Anyone can create an iPhone/Andriod/MSPhone app that leverages our api.

Bad analogy: imagine we're creating a chat api service for Steam .. and you can pay for more people in your friends list, instead of getting them via steam-experience/steam-levels. So now anyone can create a chat *client* (on any platform) .. and they use our REST api.

**So, for anyone creating an iPhone app, are we allowed to accept credit card details** and HTTPS POST them to our webserver .. where we call another payment gateway (eg. Stripe, paypal, etc.) to do the processing.

WE NEVER STORE ANYTHING ** (besides the receipt from Stripe, etc.)

Are well allowed to program this into our iPhone app? Or is that illegal? 
Can we also offer bitcoins as a payment option?

(Note: we're not really using Stripe .. but they are a well known payment processor, which helps explain this question).

Comment: "Apple's In-App Purchases are only for digital content that is delivered through your app. If you were creating an app that let people buy t-shirts, for example, you could not use IAPs. In that case, you would use something like Stripe, PayPal, etc." http://www.raywenderlich.com/30092/how-to-accept-credit-cards-in-your-ios-apps-using-stripe

Answer (score 1):

Below news is a big win for iOS developers. If it comes to effect then nothing like it.

https://in.pcmag.com/iphone-apps/144790/judge-apple-must-let-ios-apps-include-third-party-payment-options

Judge: Apple Must Let iOS Apps Include Third-Party Payment Options. The injunction, which takes effect in 90 days, threatens to upend Apple’s control over the iOS ecosystem.

As per this rule, no matter what you are selling from iOS apps, developers should be allowed to use 3rd party payment gateways.

Comment: Do you know if these rules apply worldwide including europe, or just the US?

Comment: Holy crap sticks. I asked this question back in 2014 .... eons before EPIC and Fortnite and their class action ⚡

Answer (score 0):

1. For real goodies you can not use IAP.
2. For virtual goodies consumed into your app you are allowed to integrate 3rd party payment gateway as long as you also implement IAP. Also note the price for your product through the IAP shall not be higher then through 3rd party payment gateway.
3. Also thing about your product, if it is non-consumable you need to provide mechanism to restore the purchase.

Comment: If i have to offer IAP then ... I won't be able to get any of the sale? Their client app will be linked to their own Apple Account :(

Comment: Where is your source for number 2?  App Store Review Guideline 11.2 states - **Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected**

Comment: It depends how you interpret 11.2. I had discussion about that with Apple and they said me what I'm wrote in 2. My app was released to App Store after that discussion and it utilizes both IAP and credit cards. Note: it was more than a year ago.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is - it is useless to integrate 3rd party payment systems. Even if you manage to get your app with IAP and 3rd party payment gateway to App Store for users it would be much easier to pay with IAP.