# Does Apple accept third party payment like PayPal

Tags: ios, paypal, applepay

I'm now developing iOs Mobile App payment. To make payment, I'm now planning to embed PayPal in my app. I'm not sure whether Apple accept third party payment like PayPal in app without using their native payment API call ApplePay.

Comment: probable [dupe of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154577/am-i-allowed-to-offer-payments-with-a-3rd-party-payment-gateway-for-my-iphone-a)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what is your product.

If you're selling **digital items** (for example, some in app game unlock) then you must use **In-App Purchase**.
if you're selling **real products or services**, you **have to use any other source of payment.**

[Read More at In-App-Purchase-Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf)